# open connection() method exist in which class also tell me the sub classes of the this class

Tags: url, connection

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true)
```

`openconnection()` method in this code of this class

What is the meaning of `(Httpurlconnection).` is that casting or not?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand weel your question, yes, a type in parethesis is always casting.

```
(double)x = 8;
```

forces `x`, which can be an `int` for example, to have an `double` behavior